# How can I transform a table with 1 row with varchar columns into a column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL server How can I transform 1 row with varchar columns into a column?
I think I need to use Pivot but I can't find an example without agregators

this is the situation I have:

```
create table #tmp ( ac varchar(100), bc varchar(100), cc varchar(100))
insert into #tmp (ac,bc,cc)
Values ('test1','test2','test3')

insert into #tmp
Values ('test4','test5','test6')

SELECT *
FROM #tmp
WHERE ac='test1'

drop table #tmp
```

I need to transform the result of the select in a column, I will use the result column in another nested query.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include some sample data and table structure ? Easy for us, if we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use UNPIVOT, not PIVOT

```
create table #tmp ( ac varchar(100), bc varchar(100), cc varchar(100))

insert into #tmp (ac,bc,cc)

Values ('test1','test2','test3')

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #tmp

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #tmp
UNPIVOT
(
    [Column] FOR Data IN (ac, bc, cc)
) uPIVOT


drop table #tmp
```